# how to create write a data to sdcard

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an application where I have to write the data on sdcard. I could do it in Android in older versions but with the new release it is not possible .I tried using getExternalFilesDir() function but it stores file in internal memory.

Comment: I suggest you read [the Android documentation on storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage). Pay careful attention to what the meaning of "internal" and "external" storage there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer versions you cannot write to a removable sd card with the classic file classes. (Well you still can to one app specific directory on the card getExternalFilesDirs()[1]).

For the rest use Storage Access Framework.